# Extracting specific data from a file in JAVA

Tags: java, fasta

```
>1A3B:H|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE
IVEGSDAEIGMSPWQVMLFRKSPQELLCGASLISDRWVLTAAHCLLYPPWDKNFTENDLLVRIGKHSRTRYERNIEKISM
LEKIYIHPRYNWRENLDRDIALMKLKKPVAFSDYIHPVCLPDRETAASLLQAGYKGRVTGWGNLKETWTANVGKGQPSVL
QVVNLPIVERPVCKDSTRIRITDNMFCAGYKPDEGKRGDACEGDSGGPFVMKSPFNNRWYQMGIVSWGEGCDRDGKYGFY
THVFRLKKWIQKVIDQFGE
>1A3B:I|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE
GGQSHNDGDFEEIPEEYL
>1A3B:L|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE
TFGSGEADCGLRPLFEKKSLEDKTERELLESYIDGR
```

This is the data which is stored in a text file. How do i go about extracting the data strictly  between

```
  ">1A3B:I|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE" and ">1A3B:L|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE",
```

when only

```
">1A3B:I|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE"
```

is known to us.

Also, in this given example though the data to be retrieved is only of one line, it can vary upto many lines too.
So far, i tried writing the entire content of the file to a string variable and using substring, but that logic seems to be flawed as the end index is unknown. Please help

> import java.io.*;   public class ReadingChainSpecificFastaSequence {
>
> ```
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>
>
>             File file = new File("1A3B.fasta.txt");
>             BufferedInputStream bin = null;
>
>             try
>             {
>
>                     FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
>
>
>                     bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
>
>
>                     byte[] contents = new byte[1024];
>
>                     int bytesRead=0;
>                     String strFileContents=null;
>
>                     while( (bytesRead = bin.read(contents)) != -1){
>
>                             strFileContents = new String(contents, 0, bytesRead);
>
>                     }
>                    // System.out.print(strFileContents); 
>                     String search = ">1A3B:I|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE";
>                     int start = (strFileContents.indexOf(search))+30;
>                     String search2= ">1A3B:L|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE";
>                     int end= (strFileContents.indexOf(search2));
>                    String result = strFileContents.substring(start,end);
>
>             }
>             catch(FileNotFoundException e)
>             {
>                     System.out.println("File not found" + e);
>             }
>             catch(IOException ioe)
>             {
>                     System.out.println("Exception while reading the file "+ ioe);
>             }
>             finally
>             {
>
>                     try{
>                             if(bin != null)
>                                     bin.close();
>                     }catch(IOException ioe)
>                     {
>                             System.out.println("Error while closing thestream:"+ioe);
>                     }
>
>             }
>     }
>     }
> ```

Comment: Please include your code in the question.

Comment: What do you mean by _when only `>1A3B:I|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE` is known to us._?  Do you mean that you do not know what the ending delimiter is?  This part does not make sense. Or, do you mean that the data to be extracted ends at the next line starting with `>`?

Comment: @Jim: The starting delimiter is known to us and the data to be extracted ends at the line starting with >

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to read each line of input and:

1. If `\` exists in the line, split it on this character
2. Look at the first element of the split string and break it at the `:` to find the current marker, saving the first part (`1A3B`) to a variable and the second part to another variable
3. From this "start" marker, determine what the next marker you are looking for is: by taking the first part and adding the letter after the second part to it (to form `1A3B:L`).
4. Keep reading each new line of input, storing these lines in some sort of List or array, until a line starts with the end marker (`1A3B:L`).

Answer (score 0):

Break your problem down into smaller, easier to define steps.

You know that your file has an end-of-file, and you know that your file uses the > symbol to define the beginning of the text section.

- Read file into a String.
- Find index of first >.
- Find index of next line separator.
- Interpret section header.
- Find index of next >, or end of file
- Save data between line separator and index.
- Repeat from the find index of next line separator step until the end of file.